# Android Xmppconnection with prosody server

Tags: java, android, xmpp, messaging, prosody-im

I am able to connect with my local server (prosody) but when i am trying to connect hosted server, i am unable to connect .

Here is my connection request

```
  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.XMPPTCPConnectionConfigurationBuilder builder =
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

    builder.setServiceName("my_service_name");
    builder.setHost("xx.xx.xxx.xxx"); // my host name
    builder.setPort(5281); // myport name (i have used 5281 for https as per the prosody docs )
    builder.setUsernameAndPassword(mUsername, mPassword);
    builder.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
    builder.setResource("Rooster");

    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build());
    mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
    mConnection.connect();
    mConnection.login();
```

When i am trying to connect , i am getting XmppPullparser exception as shown below , please help me.

```
W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
                                                                    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT HTTP/1.1 400 Bad...@8:1 in java.io.BufferedReader@2d9e3b7) 
                                                                        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:440)
                                                                        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:321)
                                                                        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1170)
                                                                        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:931)
```